# Reason behind different outputs for Fast Fourier Transform in Numpy and Matlab

Tags: matlab, python, numpy, fourier-transform

Here is the output of Numpy

```
np.fft.ifft([0, 4, 0, 0])
array([ 1.+0.j,  0.+1.j, -1.+0.j,  0.-1.j]) # may vary
```

Here is the output of Matlab

```
res = fft([0, 4, 0, 0])

res =

   4.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 4.0000i  -4.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 4.0000i

ifft(res)

ans =

     0     4     0     0
```

What is the reason behind different outputs for composition of FFT & iFFT in Numpy and Matlab considering that both of them are used for scientific computation?
How to remedy the problem above in Numpy so I can get the expected result?(Same result as Matlab)

Comment: How about if you run np.fft.fft([0,4,0,0]) first, then run np.fft.ifft on the resulting array? Does that match with MATLAB?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Yes it does! But why? What's the reason behind it?

Comment: I think you were misinterpreting what `np.fft` does. `np.fft` access the `fft` class -- it does not perform a discreet fourier transform. I think you meant to try `np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft([0, 4, 0, 0]))`

Comment: @CharlieS It seems that division by $N$ is not done in one of the functions. Could you please explain more why does exactly the composition `np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft([0, 4, 0, 0]))` work?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. All the results are the same as matlab. 

https://ideone.com/4Emi16

Comment: @CharlieS Basically my question is why you compose fft function two times to get `[ 4.+0.j  0.-4.j -4.+0.j  0.+4.j]` instead of just one time calling it like Matlab!

Comment: See my first comment, I believe you are misunderstanding what `np.fft.fft` is doing. The first `.fft` is accessing a set of instructions related to the FFT, including the forward FFT, the inverse FFT, and probably a bunch of other things if you read the documentation. `np.fft.fft` is only calling the FFT once.

Comment: @CharlieS Oh I see that. Basically the implementation is not as I expected. Thanks

Comment: @FreeMind No problem. It is confusing that the class has the same name as one of the routines.

Answer (score 1):

The FFT is in principle a length-preserving operation. For that there has to be a factor `1/N` to be distributed between the forward and inverse transform. It is a design decision where that is done or if it is done at all.

It appears that in both cited cases the division by `N` is performed for the inverse transform. You can interpret the ifft result as polynomial coefficients,

```
p(z) = 1 + j*z - z^2 - j*z^3
```

where you get the original vector as the polynomial values at `[1,-j,-1,j]`.